# Using CSS in my Menu Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a menu control and what im looking to do is change the color of each of the menuItem but dont have a cssClass property to do so. How could I accomplish this. Here is my code below.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu"  Orientation="horizontal"> 
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="Home"/>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="Entry">
                     <asp:MenuItem Text="New" NavigateUrl=""/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" NavigateUrl=""/>
                </asp:MenuItem>

                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="Maintenance">
                </asp:MenuItem>

                 <asp:MenuItem Text="Main Form">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Add a record" NavigateUrl=""/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit a record" NavigateUrl=""/>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Sometimes you can still access the `style` attribute even though intellisense doesn't pick it up. Have you tried that?

Comment: Have you had a look in the 'Site.Css' file? I think you can change the colour of them. Hope this helps. _**Note: It will be at the bottom, under TAB MENU**_

Comment: @user959631 What if the user doesn't have this default `Site.Css` you are referring to? What if the user only wants to change this one particular instance of `Menu`?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would scrap the use of the ASP.NET `Menu` control, and rebuild your navigation in plain, straight forward, HTML & CSS.

From my experiences with ASP.NET Menu's these generally render into *bad* HTML. I believe they render into HTML tables, which is [not what HTML tables are for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).

Furthermore, you'll then be able to style the HTML as you wish, as you'll have full control over your code.

---

That being said, there is a way of styling the `MenuItem`'s, by applying reference to the main control `CssClass`. For example, if I'm correct that Menu's use HTML tables when rendered, you could style them using the following code:

```
.menu tr td
{
   //styles here
}
```

Comment: +1 for offering a better alternative *and* answering the question.